# Create a matrix by Numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix

[image]

Please help me solve this question or give me the idea in NumPy. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please do not use images to convey text, this makes the content inaccessible for many people. Then also show what you've tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I will take notice next time.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `n` you could do it like so:

```
np.maximum(*np.meshgrid(*[np.abs(np.linspace(k:=-n+1,-k,1-2*k))]*2))+1
```